# How Call Smart contract from another network?

Tags: contract-development, javascript

I need to call a samart contract deployed in Avalanche, but my Metamask network is in Goerli, how can i call him whitout change my network?,
all this from my frontend.

Comment: it is not possible. when transaction is signed, the `chainID` is encoded in the signature so you must change the network in order for Metamask to get the correct `chainId`